# Microsoft Graph: get all users with open extensions

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

According to the docs (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/opentypeextension_get), I should be able to get all resource instances expanded with a matching extension. Say that I want to get all users which have an open extension identified by the name XXX. How can I achieve that? I've tried the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?
   $filter=Extensions/any(f:f/id eq 'assistenciasExtensions')
   &$expand=Extensions($filter=id eq 'assistenciasExtensions')
```

But it didn't work. The docs (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/opentypeextension_get) have a section called Filter for resource instances expanded with a matching extension which gives some examples and says that

"The above syntax shows some common ways to identify a resource instance or collection, in order to get an extension from it. All other syntax that allows you to identify these resource instances or collections supports getting open extensions from them in a similar way."

So, can I get all the users that have an extension or is it limited to the examples shown in the docs?

Thanks,
Luis

Answer (score 0):

Luis, Top level filter ($filter=Extensions/any(f:f/id eq 'assistenciasExtensions')) is not currently available for directory related entities (user/group/device). Please suggest the feature on user voice - https://officespdev.uservoice.com.

Thanks
Pavan

Comment: Thanks Pavan.

Quick question: is there any quick way of getting the users that belong to a group with X extension expanded? Currently, I'm loading all the users and then performing additional calls for each one to get the extension. I'm caching the data, but the first call is taking around 5secs. It's not bad, but it's also not good...

Comment: Sorry Luis, there is no way to get only members of a group of type 'user' and get extensions at the same time. However, please take a look at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching to see if your calls can be optimized.

Comment: Thanks Pavan. I'll do that!

Comment: Pavan, just one more thing: it looks like I'll have to use the REST API directly, right? I mean, a quick look at the .NET Microsoft.Graph assembly didn't show any class or method that could help me with that...

Comment: For accessing open extensions, you can use latest Microsoft Graph client library - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph. For batching, since it is in preview, library support is not available currently.

Comment: Hello again Pavan. Yes, that was what I've though. I've ended adding couple of extensions in order to support parallel batching...